# MVC application on local IIS cannot communicate with other application on same local IIS

Tags: authentication, iis, iis-7.5, ntlm, http-status-code-401

I have two applications running on my webserver. The webserver is run locally by me on my computer.

The web server is running **IIS 7.5**

I have two applications. One is a **WCF** and the other is a **MVC** application.

The MVC application is asking the WCF for data to present.

However. Having `Windows authentication` enabled on both applications, with providers `NTLM` and `Negotiate` activated.

The mvc client web.config is set like this:

```
<security mode="Transport">
    <transport clientCredentialType="Ntlm" />
</security>
```

When i send a request i get this:

> InnerExceptionMessage: "The remote server returned an error: (401)
>   Unauthorized."

along with

> ExceptionMessage: "The HTTP request is unauthorized with client
>   authentication scheme 'Ntlm'. The authentication header received from
>   the server was 'Negotiate,NTLM'."

I have googled/stackoverflowed alot for this. I've even gone so far to edit machine.config and even the IIS metabase config file. Nothing seems to work.

Short:

I'm trying to get my two applications running on the same IIS (7.5) to communicate. They're on my local computer and yet i can't seem to authenticate myself.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could maybe try this out:

Make sure that you have this set in your WCF applications `web.config` instead of your current:

```
<security mode="Transport">
   <transport clientCredentialType="Windows"/>
</security>
```

And if the MVC application and WCF Application is hosted on the same web server make sure that you use the web servers ip-address and not the external DNS-address in the binding section in your MVC application.